# How to add linear gradient to LinearProgressIndicator?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

How can you add a LinearGradient to a LinearProgressIndicator?

This is what I have now:

```
LinearProgressIndicator(
 value: 0.3,
 valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
)
```

Instead of a colour I would like to use a linear gradient.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [gradient_widgets](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/gradient_widgets) package which has a `GradientProgressIndicator` that is what I belive you're looking for.

Than you can use like so

```
GradientProgressIndicator(
                  gradient: Gradients.rainbowBlue,
                );
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a `LinearProgressIndicator`, you could used a `Container` with a gradient and fixed height. The width would correspond to the value of the linear progress indicator times the width of the screen, e.g.

```
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * <value>,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          Colors.red,
          Colors.blue
        ],
        stops: [
          0.1,
          0.5,
        ],
       ),
     ),
     child: SizedBox(
       height: 20.0,
     ),
   ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this below widget to get the Gradient progress bar

```
class GradientProgressBar extends StatelessWidget {
  ///it can be anything between 0 to 100
  final int percent;
  final LinearGradient gradient;
  final Color backgroundColor;

  const GradientProgressBar(
      {required this.percent,
      required this.gradient,
      required this.backgroundColor,
      Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: percent,
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: gradient,
              borderRadius: percent == 100
                  ? const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))
                  : const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(4),
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(4)),
            ),
            child: const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.tight,
          flex: 100 - percent,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: backgroundColor,
              borderRadius: percent == 0
                  ? const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4))
                  : const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(4),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(4)),
            ),
            child: const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Sample Usage

```
 const GradientProgressBar(
                  percent: 0,
                  gradient: Gradients.primaryGradient,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly an answer to the question, but check out https://pub.dev/packages/step_progress_indicator (which doesn't seem to have existed when the question was asked).

From their page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it this way where progress is from 0-1

```
Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            gradient: LinearGradient(colors: const [
              Color(0xFF2607E7),
              Color(0xFF57C0EF),
              Colors.grey,
            ], stops: [
              progress / 2,
              progress,
              progress,
            ])),
        child: const SizedBox(height: 10),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use linearGradient property to add linear gradient to LinearProgressIndicator. For example:

`LinearPercentIndicator( lineHeight: 24.h,  barRadius: Radius.circular(30.r), percent: 0.25, linearGradient: LinearGradient(colors: [ Colors.green, Colors.Red ]), )`